# Setting "cm" as default unit of measures in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is there a way in order to avoid to manually setting the unit of measures in every line of a tikzpicture code? For instance there is a way in order to just write `xshift=+3` instead of `xshift=+3cm`?

Comment: it is already in cm by default

Comment: @percusse Yes, but `xshift`/`yshift` requires a dimension, so a unitless number is read as `pt`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes that one *requires*(!) a dimen so there is no escape from that. In other places where it is optional cm is the default unit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your own shift

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[myx/.style={xshift=#1*1cm}, myy/.style={yshift=#1*1cm}]
\draw[style=help lines] (-2,-2) grid[step=1] (1,1);
\draw ([myx=-1,myy=-1]0,0) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, for instance,  if you use `myx=+1`  it will not work. To solve the problem: `myx/.style={xshift=(#1)*1cm}`

Comment: @AndreaLeo Don't use `+` as the first char of calculations for positive numbers. It might have strange effects. PGF treats that as *don't worry there is no calculation happening, parse it directly* signal.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
shift={(3,0)}
```

instead of `xshift=3cm`.

It's not less verbose, but it does mean that shifts will change if you change the unit vectors.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [shift={(-0.5,-0.5)}] (0,0) grid (4,1);

\node {a};
\node [shift={(3,0)}] {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```