# Drawing a schematic of a DC motor circuit with a mechanical load connected to the rotor

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

For the following schematic of an electromechanical system, I would like to:

1- reduce and optimize the code as much as possible for the following:

- drawing a line from its center by specifying its length and rotation (e.g. the line below `N_1` and above `N_2`)
- find a more compact way to position and draw the pattern-filled rectangle instead of defining coordinates
- find a more optimized way to place the twisted arrows halfway between the vertical lines and the motor and cylinder

2- center the current arrow `i_a` between the resistance and the inductance,

3- understand the reason behind the existence of the gap between `(M1.east)` and the horizontal line next to it.

4- know why do I need to write down the unit `mm` for `xshift` and `yshift` to make it work as expected.

5- move `E_a` with its positive and negative signs to the right to be horizontally aligned with the circuit terminals. i.e. both signs and terminals and `E_a` should be horizontally aligned.

**Further recommendations and code reductions are highly appreciated.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc, positioning, patterns, decorations, decorations.markings}

\newcommand{\mymotor}[2] % #1 = name , #2 = rotation angle
{\draw[thick,rotate=#2] (#1) circle (10pt)
    node[]{$\mathsf M$} 
    ++(-12pt,3pt)--++(0,-6pt) --++(2.5pt,0) ++(-2.8pt,6pt)-- ++(2.5pt,0pt);
    \draw[thick,rotate=#2] (#1) ++(12pt,3pt)--++(0,-6pt) --++(-2.5pt,0) ++(2.8pt,6pt)-- ++(-2.5pt,0pt);
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[damper/.style={thick,
            decorate,
            decoration={markings,  
                mark connection node=dmp,
                mark=at position 0.5 with 
                {
                    \node (dmp) [thick, inner sep=0pt, 
                    transform shape, 
                    rotate=-90, 
                    minimum width=15pt, 
                    minimum height=10pt, draw=none] {};
                    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(4pt,0)$) -- 
                    (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- 
                    ($(dmp.north west)+(4pt,0)$);
                    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-8pt)$) -- 
                    ($(dmp.north)+(0,8pt)$);
        }}},]

        \draw (0,2) to[R=$R_a$,o-,  f=$i_a$] ++(2,0)  to[L,cute inductor, l=$L_a$,]  ++(2,0)  to[sV, color=white, name=M1] ++(0,-2) to[short,-o] ++(-4,0);
        \mymotor{M1}{90}

        \draw (0,2) to [open, v=$E_a$] (0,0);

        \draw[thick] (M1.north) -- ++(1.5,0) -- +(0,0.5) node [anchor=south] {$N_1$} -- +(0,-0.5) coordinate (N1);

        \draw[->] ([xshift=7.5mm,yshift=-2mm]M1.north)  to [out=-60,in=60, looseness=4] ++(0,0.4) node [above=1mm] {$T_m, \theta_m$};

        \draw[thick] ([yshift=-2]N1) -- ++(0,-1.5) node [below] {$N_2$} ++(0,0.75) -- ++(1,0) node [cylinder, black, shape border rotate=180, draw,
        minimum height=2, minimum width=1, aspect=0.5,cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder end fill = gray!20,anchor=west] (c) {Load Inertia};

        \draw[->] ([xshift=-5mm,yshift=-2mm]c.west)  to [out=-120,in=120, looseness=4] ++(0,0.4) node [above=1mm] {$\theta_L$};

        \draw [damper] (c.east) -- node[above=3mm] {$d_1$} ++(0:2) ++(0,-1) coordinate (pttrn);


        \draw[preaction={fill=gray!10},pattern=north east lines,pattern=bricks] (pttrn) rectangle ++(0.5,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming you really need to do the cylinder in one stretch, you could do `\draw[thick] ([yshift=-2]N1) -- ++(0,-1.5) node [below] {$N_2$} 
  coordinate[midway] (aux) (aux) -- ++ (1,0)
   node [anchor=top,right,cylinder, black, shape border rotate=180, draw,
        minimum height=2, minimum width=1, aspect=0.5,cylinder uses custom fill,
  cylinder end fill = gray!20,
  path picture={\draw($(c.before top)!0.5!(c.after top)$) -- (c.top);}] (c) {Load Inertia};`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for your consideration :)

Comment: The problem is that  the `cylinder end fill` is rather "violent", so it always goes in front, which prevents simpler solutions. If you want simpler solutions, you may need something like [this definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451147) of a filled cylinder, which also allows more fancy shadings.  Similar ordering problems appear [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507687).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for referring me to these questions. May I know what `coordinate[midway] (aux) (aux)` means to be used instead of `++(0,0.75)`?

Comment: Well, it will always be in the middle, also if you change the dimensions. It is a matter of taste which option one considers "better".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1

> find a more optimized way to place the twisted arrows halfway between
>   the vertical lines and the motor and cylinder

Define a `pic` and use.

```
\tikzset{rotarrow/.pic={
\draw[thin,->] (-0.2,-0.2)  to [out=-60,in=60, looseness=4] ++(0,0.4) node [above=1mm] {\tikzpictext};
},
}

% \draw (0,0) -- pic[pic text={$\theta$}]{rotarrow} ++(1.5,0); %<-use pic
```

#### 2

Use a short in between resistor and inductor and use flow arrow there.

```
\draw (0,2) to[R=$R_a$,o-] ++(2,0) to[short,f=$i_a$] ++(0.1,0) to[L,cute inductor, l=$L_a$,]  ++(2,0)  to[sV, color=white, name=M1] ++(0,-2) to[short,-o] (0,0);
```

#### 3

`M1` is a sinusoidal voltage source (`sV`). So its trying to access the `east` node of `sV` not `mymotor`. You can fix it by increasing the radius of circle in `\mymotor`. Or you can just use the `elmech` element.

```
\draw (M1) node[elmech,scale=0.7]{M};
```

#### 4

Default unit is `pt`. See this questions: [Different dimensions with shift and xshift](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469893/28557) and [Setting “cm” as default unit of measures in tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407825/28557)

#### 5

Use tikz path

```
\path (0,2)node[below]{+} -- node[midway]{$E_a$} (0,0)node[above]{-};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc, positioning, patterns, decorations, decorations.markings,quotes}
\tikzset{rotarrow/.pic={
\draw[thin,->] (-0.2,-0.2)  to [out=-60,in=60, looseness=4] ++(0,0.4) node [above=1mm] {\tikzpictext};
},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[damper/.style={thick,
            decorate,
            decoration={markings,  
                mark connection node=dmp,
                mark=at position 0.5 with 
                {
                    \node (dmp) [thick, inner sep=0pt, 
                    transform shape, 
                    rotate=-90, 
                    minimum width=15pt, 
                    minimum height=10pt, draw=none] {};
                    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(4pt,0)$) -- 
                    (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- 
                    ($(dmp.north west)+(4pt,0)$);
                    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-8pt)$) -- 
                    ($(dmp.north)+(0,8pt)$);
        }}},]

        \draw (0,2) to[R=$R_a$,o-] ++(2,0) to[short,f=$i_a$] ++(0.1,0) to[L,cute inductor, l=$L_a$,]  ++(2,0)  to[short,  name=M1] ++(0,-2) to[short,-o] (0,0);
        \draw (M1) node[elmech,scale=0.7](M2){M};
        \path (0,2)node[below]{+} -- node[midway]{$E_a$} (0,0)node[above]{-};
        \draw[thick] (M2.east) -- pic[pic text={$T_m,\theta_m$}]{rotarrow} ++(1.5,0) -- +(0,0.5) node [anchor=south] {$N_1$} -- +(0,-0.5) coordinate (N1);

        \draw[thick] ([yshift=-2]N1) -- ++(0,-1.5) node [below] {$N_2$} ++(0,0.75) --  pic[xscale=-1,pic text={$\theta_L$}]{rotarrow} ++(1,0) node [cylinder, black, shape border rotate=180, draw,
        minimum height=2, minimum width=1, aspect=0.5,cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder end fill = black!70,anchor=west,xshift=-0.15cm, fill opacity=0.2,text opacity=1] (c) {Load Inertia};
        \draw [damper] (c.east) -- node[above=3mm] {$d_1$} ++(0:2)   node[draw, rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width =0.5cm,anchor=west,preaction={fill=gray!10},pattern=north east lines,pattern=bricks]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Would you please provide a full MWE to understand the implementation of point  `1(c)` and `3`.

Comment: @Diaa I have added the full code

Comment: I appreciate your help. Is it possible to draw the horizontal line from the gear `N2` to the center of the cylinder face (i.e. `( $(<name>.before top)!0.5!(<name>.after top)$ )`)  in one single step without having to draw the cylinder first before the horizontal line then refer to it when drawing the line?

Comment: Furthermore, the current flow `i_a` is perfectly centered between the resistor and the inductance; is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I meant `i_a` with its arrow to be horizontally aligned between the resistor and the inductance.

Comment: It is my bad; the difference between the lengths of the left leg of the inductance and the right leg of the resistor deceived me.

Comment: @Diaa see updated answer.

Comment: Many thanks. May I know if `xshift=-0.15cm` is calculated or guessed?

Comment: @Diaa  I guessed the value