Mechanical System of Torsional Dynamics Using CircuiTikz
I am trying to create the following figure in LaTeX:

If anybody can guide me, I would appreciate it.

My attempt was super ugly:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
        (0,0) to[L] (2,0)
        (2,0) to[transmission line] (4,0)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}

I clearly need guidance here.

Update:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[->] (.25,.25) edge [bend right=-90] node [above=.25] {\(\theta_{i}\)} (.25,-.25);
    \draw (0,0) to[cute inductor, l_=\(K\)] (2,0);
    \node[cylinder, black, shape border rotate=180, draw, minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=.75cm, aspect=0.5, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder end fill = gray!20, anchor=west] (c) at (2,0) {\(J\)};
    \path[->] (3.75,.25) edge [bend right=-90] node [above=.25] {\(\theta_{o}\)} (3.75,-.25);
    \draw (3.5,0) to[damper, l_=\(B\)] (5.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I give it another attempt after learning the suggestions in the comments. The result is better now, but the damper component is completely different and I haven't added the bearing supports. Can someone help me how to draw the same damper as in the figure and maybe let me know how to draw the dashed squares?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514350/drawing-a-schematic-of-a-dc-motor-circuit-with-a-mechanical-load-connected-to-th and try to draw an example, post if you get stuck

I would not use circuitikz for that but rather just TikZ.

Thanks for the comments. Sorry for that! You're right, I appreciate it. :-) @hpekristiansen

Thanks! I checked the question you attached, which seems similar to mine. Can I ask what the 'mymotor' is used for? @Rmano

It's just a macro, I think; it's used in the main drawing.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, arrows.meta, patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (4,0) to[damper, l_=\(B\)] (6,0);
\node[cylinder, black, shape border rotate=180, draw, minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=1cm, aspect=0.5, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=cyan!50, cylinder end fill=gray!20, anchor=west] (c) at (2.5,0) {\(J\)};
\draw (0,0) -- (0.4,0) to[cute inductor, l_=\(K\)] (2.6,0);
\draw[xshift=0.2cm, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}] (0,0.25) to[bend right=-90] node[above=.25, font=\small] {\(\theta_{i}\)} +(0,-0.5) node[left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{\(+\)};
\draw[xshift=4.3cm, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}] (0,0.25) to[bend right=-90] node[above=.25, font=\small] {\(\theta_{o}\)} +(0,-0.5) node[left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{\(+\)};
\draw[xshift=0.7cm, pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=1.5pt]}, pattern color=blue] (0,0.1) rectangle +(0.2,0.5) (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.2,-0.5);
\draw[xshift=2.1cm, pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=1.5pt]}, pattern color=blue] (0,0.1) rectangle +(0.2,0.5) (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.2,-0.5);
\draw[xshift=5.5cm, pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=1.5pt]}, pattern color=blue] (0,0.1) rectangle +(0.2,0.5) (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Alternative damper:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, arrows.meta, patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (4,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[semithick, <->, >={_[sep=-2pt].Bracket[sep=-2pt, width=8pt, length=5pt]}] (5,0.5) -- (5,-0.5) node[below=2pt] {\(B\)};
\node[cylinder, black, shape border rotate=180, draw, minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=1cm, aspect=0.5, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=cyan!50, cylinder end fill=gray!20, anchor=west] (c) at (2.5,0) {\(J\)};
\draw (0,0) -- (0.4,0) to[cute inductor, l_=\(K\)] (2.6,0);
\draw[xshift=0.2cm, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}] (0,0.25) to[bend right=-90] node[above=.25, font=\small] {\(\theta_{i}\)} +(0,-0.5) node[left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{\(+\)};
\draw[xshift=4.3cm, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}] (0,0.25) to[bend right=-90] node[above=.25, font=\small] {\(\theta_{o}\)} +(0,-0.5) node[left=-2pt, font=\tiny]{\(+\)};
\draw[xshift=0.7cm, pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=1.5pt]}, pattern color=blue] (0,0.1) rectangle +(0.2,0.5) (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.2,-0.5);
\draw[xshift=2.1cm, pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=1.5pt]}, pattern color=blue] (0,0.1) rectangle +(0.2,0.5) (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.2,-0.5);
\draw[xshift=5.5cm, pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=1.5pt]}, pattern color=blue] (0,0.1) rectangle +(0.2,0.5) (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Note that almost everything is custom, so it makes little sense to use circuitikz.

Thank you so much! Can I ask one thing? I am new to using LaTeX to draw figures. What does xshift do in \draw[xshift=0.7cm, pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance=1.5pt]}, pattern color=blue] (0,0.1) rectangle +(0.2,0.5) (0,-0.1) rectangle +(0.2,-0.5);?

xshift does an x-shift. Not sure I can explain it differently. Try to change the value and you will see what happens.

Yep, you need just to substitute the coil and you can drop the circuitikz dependency completely (which I admit would be good, given its weight and lack of modularity). Probably doable with some decoration...
